# can someone help with this graphing math question?

Tags: graphing-functions

The diagram shows the line $2y=x+5$ and the curve $y=x^2-4x+7$, which intersects the points A and B. How do you find the $x$-coordinates and also the equation of the tangent to the curve at B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2y=x+5$ implies $y=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{5}{2}$

Let $y=y$, namely $\frac{x}{2}+\frac{5}{2}=x^2-4x+7$

Solve for real $x$, should they exist...

As for the tangent, take the derivative of the curve with respect to $x$, namely 
$$y'(B)=2(B)-4$$

Evaluate $$\lim_{h->0}\frac{(B+h)^2-4(B+h)+7-B^2+4B-7}{h}$$

Comment: for the tangent, what do you do once you get the derivative...i am still a bit confused yet...

Comment: you use the x that you found previously?

Comment: Yes, namely x = B.

Comment: and h is?....sorry i am not very good at understanding math

Comment: actually i figured it out